# Can't Remove Soundflower From OS X El Capitain

Tags: macos, mac, audio, uninstall

I installed soundflower found here:
https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/ , a while back. I have removed every trace of it on my mac. I used the uninstaller script provided with Soundflower and went in and manually searched for the files and removed whatever I found.
I even removed it from the 2 plist files `com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist` and `com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist` found in the `/Library/Preferences/Audio` folder and it still shows up in my Sound preferences as a selection. It's not causing any issues, but it is really bothering me and I would like it completely gone. Here is a screenshot of what shows in my sound system settings

[image]

Can anyone help me with where I would go with this next?

Answer (score 4):

You probably left behind the extension itself.

I think different versions put the file in either `/System/Library/Extensions` or `/Library/Extensions`
Check both for a leftover Soundflower.kext, discard & reboot.

Comment: `/Library/Extensions` is the location I overlooked. Thanks!